# Rails Connecting to database specified by database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, connection

I recently restarted POW. On reloading the Rails app I'm working on, it hung.

Checking Rails' logs I get the following repeating every 5-20 seconds:

`Connecting to database specified by database.yml`

I can interact with the Postgres db without issue through the Rails console, so there is no problem there. I haven't changed anything in my database.yml for weeks, so I don't think the problem is there.

What might be the problem and how can I debug it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was caused by POW

I had set '$powder always_restart` which was causing some sort of loop.

I reset this using `$ powder no_restarts'

Answer (score 0):

Change your production database temporary to your development settings.

Then run in your terminal:
rails console production

Most of the times it is not about your database, but probably a syntax error. Anyways you can debug it like this.