# what does "Connecting to database specified by database.yml" in the log file mean?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a Rails 3.2.9 app , on performing a certain action, the app doesnt go any further and when i chech the log file i get this line to be the last in the log

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

I have no idea what's causing this problem.. When i sign up or sign in also it needs to connect to db and it works fine then.. only when a function (called execute test case) is clicked, the app doesnt go further and freezes there itself..

Please help me if you have come across this ...or suggest what may be the cause!!

Comment: are you using mysql2 gem..?

Comment: Yes i have that gem.. May be the client library version is having some problems.. I'm using MYSQL Server 5.5.14 and gem is gem 'mysql2', '> 0.3.1'... Is the version of gem wrong?? We need to a dll called libmysql.dll from MYSQL to Ruby folder. When I put the one available in MYSQL folder it gives error so I'm using the one that is compatible and it works well . But only on a certain action its giving the above error... 

PS: the same dll and mysql server works fine in my colleagues machine!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this error.. Problem is when the **gem ‘mysql2’ is installed for the app , it might not be the one compatible with the version of MySQL server** that is installed in our machine. And also a corresponding  libmysql.dll file to be copied to Ruby folder.
So install the gem by specifying the local directory of Mysql

1.In the cmd,

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=C:\Program Files\MySQL
```

1. As directed in the cmd, follow the link to download the dll. Extract the zip from that location and copy the file as instructed in cmd

If the zip is empty or the link shows file not exist.(which does happen for some versions!!)

--> Go to the link and follow the flow in the url.. Like the website.. http://dev.mysql.com ->downloads -> MySQL Connectors -> MySQL Connector/C -> the latest version zips are displayed.. Choose the one with the exact file name as in the empty zip/broken link. If not click on previous GA versions and find the according zip file. Download, extract and copy the libmysql.dll to Ruby’s bin folder

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer. This may help you.

[Rails Connecting to database specified by database.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498451/rails-connecting-to-database-specified-by-database-yml)