# Does "Connecting to database specified by database.yml" simply indicate that the server has started

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking though my production log to investigate a bug on a rails 3.2 app. When getting the server back up, I restarted the app. The only evidence for the restart in the production log seems to be this entry:

> Connecting to database specified by database.yml

Is this the only occasion when this message will appear? That is, can I always assume this message indicates an app start?

Searching stackoverflow, the references I find to this log output seem to look upon it as an error. For example:

[what does "Connecting to database specified by database.yml" in the log file mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585979/what-does-connecting-to-database-specified-by-database-yml-in-the-log-file-mea?s=2|2.7349)

However, I think this is in fact the last successful log message before the error. That is, it is not an error message, but rather indicates that the app got as far as initiating the connection to the database, before the error occurred.

Having this as the only log output on app restart seems confusing to me (and from the other stackoverflow entries, it confuses others too).

I've added an initializer 'config/initializers/log_app_start.rb' to my app with this content:

```
Rails.logger.info 'App starting: Initializer called'
```

I now get this in the log on restart:

> Connecting to database specified by database.yml
>
> App starting: Initializer called

Which at least adds some context to the log entry. However, it would be nice to have the 'App starting' before the 'Connecting to database' entry.

Is there a better way to log app restarts in the production logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question has been sat here for four months without an answer, I think the answer is:

Yes,

> Connecting to database specified by database.yml

in a rails log simply indicates that the server has restarted.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when your app server (puma, unicorn, passenger, etc) or your background processing gem such as sucker_punch, sidekiq, etc initiates a new thread it will connect to the database and open a connection.  The number of connections the app/background processor is allowed to hit is in your database.yml file.  When setting your pool count in database.yml you need to account for a multi-threaded server such as puma or a background processing gem that uses threads for operations such as sucker_punch or sidekiq.

You will also see this information in the log when you boot your app for the first time.  Also rake/runner tasks will flag this info into the logger since it loads the rails environment and if there's any ActiveRecord stuff happening it will need a db connection outside of the app's main thread(s).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes - I hadn't considered the multi-threaded or multi-server-instance scenarios. As you say, that could add further complication.

Comment: Glad I could offer an explanation.  It took me a bit to wrap my head around it at first too.  Good things to take into consideration when judging your db pool limits.